# Auto return type of a function in c++

Tags: c++, function, templates, auto

I have a problem that Im not able to solve. I have tried to find similar question here, but didnt find working solution for me.

My structure is:

```
class Base
{
    unsigned int ID;
};

class Position: public Base
{
    float x,y;

    Position(float a, float b): x(a), y(b) {}
}

class Mass: public Base
{
    float mass;

    Mass(float a): mass(a) {}
}
```

I store pointers to all attributes in a map accesed with strings.
I would like to have a function, that can return any attribute from this list using names.
Structure and desired functionality should be like this:

```
std::map<string, Base*> attributes;

???? getAtt(string name)
{
    return attributes[name];
}

Position pos(1,2);
Mass mass(25.6);
attributes.emplace("TEST_POSITION", &pos);
attributes.emplace("TEST_MASS") &mass);

cout << "Mass of this object is " <<getAtt("TEST_MASS").mass << endl;
cout << "X - Position of this object is " << getAtt("TEST_POSITION").x ;

PRINTS:  Mass of this object is 25.6
         X - Position of this object is 1
```

This function, addition of attributes and memory managment should be encapsuled in another class, but I think that wont be such problem after i get this thing solved.
So is there a way to do that? I was thinking about templates, but I dont understand them enough to make them work :( I was thinking about not storing all attributes in one array, but this way it is really easy.
Thanks for any suggestions :)

Comment: Are you intentionally mixing attributes of different types? It often is easier to have multiple homogeneous containers than one heterogeneous container.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler cannot deduce the return type without you hinting it. You can use a template for that:

```
template <typename T>
T& getAtt(string name)
{
    return dynamic_cast<T&>(*attributes.at(name));
}
```

Edit: use `at` instead of `[]`, `[]` has the side-effect that it creates non-existing keys.

And then call it like this:

```
getAtt<Mass>("TEST_MASS").mass
getAtt<Position>("TEST_POSITION").x
```

However, this code would be nightmare to debug. Try to avoid generic attributes and use strong-typed variables, ie. instead of:

```
std::map<string, Base*> attributes;
attributes.emplace("mass", Mass(…));
attributes.emplace("position", Position(…));
```

use:

```
Mass mass;
Position position;
```

Comment: Thank you, that template works.
I would like to add these attributes at runtime, so thats why i needed that map. Because i can add and removes attributes from it.
I wanted to make a small physics simulation with stars - gravity and that kind of stuff.
And I wanted to have it nicely packed and readable.

Comment: @Quimby Templates are compile-time feature only, they cannot be instantiated in runtime so whatever you will do with them, you can also do with strong-typed variables. Moreover you will very soon notice that generic attributes may be everything but are definitely not packed or easily readable.

Comment: @Quimby: Why add arbitrary attributes, when the code won't know what to do with them? And if you add code to handle simulating those attributes then you can add code to read the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Your getAtt will return a Base*, like this:

```
Base* getAtt(const string& name)
{
...
}
```

But Base class doesn't provide a interface for all its derived class, so you can't just do

```
getAtt("TEST_MASS").mass
```

instead you have to do this:

```
dynamic_cast<Mass*>(getAtt("TEST_MASS"))->mass;
dynamic_cast<Position*>(getAtt("TEST_POSITION"))->x;
```

There are alternatives, for example you can use a tagged union, but that might be too complex for your problem.

By the way, [] operator of map will create a element if it doesn't exist, so you need to check getAtt isn't returning a nullptr.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a reference object that has a conversion operator to the type. If the conversion is implemented with a dynamic cast, the result will be NULL if an attempt is made to assign the object to something that it is not. Dynamic cast requires `Base` to have a virtual method (you could just add a virtual destructor).

```
class Base {
    unsigned int ID;
protected:
    virtual ~Base () {}
};

class Ref {
    friend Ref getAtt (std::string name);
    Base *ref_;
    Ref (Base *p = 0) : ref_(p) {}
public:
    template <typename D> operator D * () const {
        return dynamic_cast<D *>(ref_);
    }
};

Ref getAtt (std::string name) { return attributes[name]; }
```

This technique does not allow you to treat a `Ref` as any particular type. It allows you to assign it to something that it is allowed to become.

```
Mass *m = getAtt("TEST_MASS");
Position *p = getAtt("TEST_POSITION");
cout << "Mass of this object is " << m->mass << endl;
cout << "X - Position of this object is " << p->x ;
```

If the resulting pointer is NULL, it means either the item did not exist, or you are attempting to assign it to the wrong thing.

```
Position *p = getAtt("TEST_MASS");
assert(p == NULL);
```

Comment: Thank you, that look really nice. I will definitely try it :)